# Syntax Error in etc/sudoers and can't edit it in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, sudo

I was/am trying to run terminal commands without having to use sudo first and must have broke the file. Now I'm trying to fix it and it's giving me this error when I try to edit with the same `sudo visudo` command.

> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 62 <<<
> sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 62
> sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
> sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I'm on a Mac using Terminal

Is there a way to edit this file and remove what I added or reset it without harming or removing other files?

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot su to root and edit the sudoers file directly?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Because root is not enabled. The obvious answer is to copy the file back from a backup - although admin role might be broken as well - so do it rebooting into single user mode

Comment: @mmmmmm The OP didn't say that. How do you know that?

Comment: @FeliniusRex because it is the macOS default so it is best to assume that root is not enabled. If you have enabled root I would assume you don't really use sudo